# {lslide} {bbding} ERROR dvipdf

Tags: errors, dvipdf

I have the following problem.When I use `lslide` package togeahther with `bbding` (to be able to use `\RightHand` character) I get the following error when translating from dvi to pdf.

```
$ dvipdf random.dvi
dvips: Font bbding10 not found; using cmr10
dvips: Checksum mismatch in font bbding10
```

However, when translating first to ps and then to pdf, everything goes smoothly.
How to fix dvipdf command?

TRY THIS:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{lslide}  


\usepackage{enumitem,bbding,etoolbox,calc}  

\makeatletter  
\pretocmd{\@chooseSymbol}{\raisebox{-.5ex}[\height-.5ex][0pt]}{}{}  
\makeatother  

\begin{document}  
\begin{itemize}[label=\HandRight]  
\item abc  

\item[\PencilRight] def  
\end{itemize}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem? It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Does this example work to you without errors?

Comment: What is the `lslide` package? It doesn't seem to be part of a standard TeX distribution. Where can the `.sty` file be found?

Comment: There can be found some via google,but to be sure we use the same,I've uploaded it here  http://ulozto.cz/xxwYRNxY/lslide-sty

Answer (score 3):

The `dvipdf` script is quite old and superseded by better ones: prefer

```
latex file; dvips file -o; ps2pdf file
```

or, directly,

```
pdflatex file
```

If you add, at the start of your document,

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
```

and run

```
arara -v file
```

you'll get the three above steps done automatically. You need an up-to-date TeX distribution, of course.